# css: set font-weight

Tags: css

Is it possible to set font-weight to `normal` without `!important`?

http://jsfiddle.net/DvBes/

```
<table id="tasks">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>SomeTask</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Time</td><td class="gray">08/11/2011</td></tr>
</table>



table#tasks td:first-child+td {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.gray {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first css rule is much more specific than the second, because of this it will overwrite the second one if you don't use `!important`.

You could achieve the same without `!important` by changing `.gray` to `table#tasks td:first-child+td.gray`

Comment: I did it this way but I thought it could be a little bit shorter

Comment: You also don't need to specify `table` in `table#tasks`, since there should only be one element with ID `tasks` on the page. I believe there might even be a performance benefit.

Comment: Just `#tasks td:first-child+td.gray`? Is there any case when as a selector could use something like `element#id` in CSS? I forgot where and why I used `table#tasks`

Comment: Not sure why the spec has that as an example, but that's not necessary. As derekerdmann said, there should only ever be one element with that ID (that's the point of ID, to be unique). Also, instead of having that crazy line of CSS, make use of the `<th>` tag instead. Even if they are on the left, instead of the top, the first cells in your row qualify, semantically, as title cells, so `<th>` is appropriate. Depending on your goal, you can then just use `td` as your selector to make the text bold, and simply `.gray` will work as you originally expected.

Comment: @Shauna I can use `th` in a several rows? Like this http://jsfiddle.net/DvBes/11/?

Comment: @johnny - Yeah. That's pretty much exactly what `th` is for. Check out the example after section 4.9.2 in the WhatWG documentation - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-table-element Note the numbers that are bold, both sets are using `th`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code would do the trick:

```
#tasks .gray {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

You need to learn a bit about selector specificity, here's a good article http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/ on it.

Comment: The question specifically mentioned _not_ using `!important`

Comment: Oh, sorry, `!important` is unnecessary here, I just forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Spadar Shut in this case I get not only gray but bold

Comment: That's weird, because `#tasks .gray` has greater specificity, probably there's something else  interfering with the styles. Try to open up Firebug and inspect he element to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your CSS:

```
.gray {
    color: gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

to

```
table#tasks td:first-child+td.gray, .gray {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, give it greater [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)

```
table#tasks tr td.gray
```

Comment: You are missing the `td` before `.gray`